# Ignoring XML tags in XSL

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a question regarding XML translations , I have an XML that I translate to another XML .
My xls is pretty straightforward , just taking the fields I want . What I notice though is that if for example I have 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 and in my xsl I just decide i want 1,3 that 2 will come with it as well. I believe I read about xsl going by default rules and such so:...

Do I need to create a rule for each tag, even the ones I don't want?.
How do I handle ones I do not want ?. ( I tried a few things but it still outputs it).
Is there any tutorials or good pages on straight XML 2 XML translations?.

All insight is great, I am away to google more.

Thanks.

This is my XSL as it currently stands without the Match Filter on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <!--FileImport-->

    <xsl:template match="FileImport">
        <FileImport>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </FileImport>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Start-->
    <xsl:template match="Start">
        <Start>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Start>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StartParam">
        <StartParam>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </StartParam>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- CLip -->
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="'|clip|number|technical_comments|channel|'" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Clip">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=
                "*[contains($fields, concat('|', @name, '|'))]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And a bit of my XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<FileImport>
    <Global>
        <GlobalParam name="RollName" value="Scene1" />
        <GlobalParam name="TapeOrg" value="10:00:00:00" />
        <GlobalParam name="ReadStart" value="00:00:00:00" />
        <GlobalParam name="ReadDuration" value="00:02:26:18" />
    </Global>
    <Roll>
        <Field name="ingest_report" value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;  standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;DataSet1 
        </Roll>
        <Clip>
            <Field name="audio_format" value="" group="Ingest" />
            <Field name="camera_id" value="" group="Ingest" />
        </Clip>

    </FileImport>
```

And Hopefully my output will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="testFIDEF.xsl"?>

<FileImport>
    <Global>
        <GlobalParam name="RollName" value="Scene_Around_Six_Tape_3_BUFVC003-14 10:00:00:00" />
        <GlobalParam name="TapeOrg" value="10:00:00:00" />
        <GlobalParam name="ReadStart" value="00:00:00:00" />
        <GlobalParam name="ReadDuration" value="00:02:26:18" />
    </Global>

    <MasterClip>
        <Field name="clip_description" value="Interview Captain Austin Ardill re Terence O'Neill" group="Ingest" />
        <Field name="rushes_roll_number" value="BUFVC003" group="Ingest" />
        <Field name="source_image_format" value="" group="Ingest" />
        <Field name="technical_comments" value="" group="Ingest" />
    </MasterClip>
</FileImport>
```

Comment: It would be really useful if you posted some code so we can see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: It really depends on the design of your transform.

Comment: What you are showing it's still not enough I think. For example, by the instruction `<xsl:apply-templates />` you apply the templates to all the children of the current context. If you do not explicitely manage those children, the built-in rules will work in the background, thus making some surprise. You should show the XML input and the wanted output now.

Comment: IMHO, it's not possible to make an XSLT processor parse non well-formed XML input and generate a non well-formed output. Not to mention the indention of your samples :)))

Comment: Sorry but the Xml is well formed , the indents was me not using the code button and just using space bar. I ran it through w3 school xml and the input seems fine. I'm just trying to not display the "roll" tag away. I could edit the file in c# but I think it can be done , just that I am not doing it right , very new to XSL.

Comment: @user now that I've made your code more readable you should fix the `field` tag on your "bit of XML" because it does not make sense. Moreover you should explain why in your transform you are matching elements not present in your input. This at least, if you still want an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The sample input XML where <clip> should be <MasterClip> FYI. in Masterclip I have lots and lots of fields and just want to pick about 5. preceding that is roll tag , which i need to remove as it contains info that's not relevant to the project. The search works and it only returns the one's I specify but obviously i don't want  <roll> to come along with the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default transforms will out the value of any text node if there is not a match with another template rule. You can avoid this by adding the template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*" />
```

This will override the default rule for text and attributes. This does mean that you will need to explicitly select the values for text to be output using `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: And where do I place this in the xsl?. I assumed it was at the beginning but it still does not work!

Comment: It is best to place it first so that it doesn't affect later rules. If the node is being matched by another rule then is may still have its value output. Could you include some code in your question that replicates the issue?

Comment: Could you also include a snippet of your XML to test against and the desired output?

Comment: Xml and desired output inserted there for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments:

> *The search works and it only returns the one's I specify but obviously i don't want `<roll>` to come along with the output.*

Look at this part of your transform:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Such a template is known as **Identity Transformation**. Because its task is to copy everything in the input to the output, when you use it in a transform you **must explicitely shut up** the unwanted elements. As per your comments, if you do not want `roll` you need a template like:

```
<xsl:template match="roll"/>
```

That is, you override the identity and make the transform do nothing for that element.